# Swift: Decode arbitrary protocol types

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to decode JSON that has a variable property which conforms to a protocol.

Consider the following set of structs:

```swift
protocol P: Decodable {
    var id: String { get }
}

struct A: P {
    let id: String
    var someThing: Double
}

struct B: P {
    let id: String
    var anotherThing: String
}

struct S: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let instanceOfProtocol: P
}
```

We're trying to decode `S`.

The automatic synthesis of `Decodable` does not work (because the decoder can't know which type `P` is going to be decoded to) so I'm trying to do this in a custom initializer:

## Option 1: Exhaustively Check Conforming Types:

```swift
if let instance = try? container.decode(A.self, forKey: .instanceOfProtocol) {
    instanceOfProtocol = instance
} else if let instance = try? container.decode(B.self, forKey: .instanceOfProtocol) {
    instanceOfProtocol = instance
} else {
    throw NoConformingTypeError()
}
```

This works, but is very verbose, repetitive, and doesn't scale well, so I'm looking for other options.

## Option 2: (Ab)use `superDecoder`:

```swift
let possibleTypes: [P.Type] = [A.self, B.self]
let childDecoder = try container.superDecoder(forKey: .instanceOfProtocol)
let decoded: [P] = possibleTypes.compactMap { try? $0.init(from: childDecoder) }
guard let instance = decoded.first else { throw NoConformingTypeError() }
instanceOfProtocol = instance
```

This works as well, but I'm not sure if `superDecoder` is meant to be used this way, or if it will break in the future.

## Option 3:

```swift
let possibleTypes: [P.Type] = [A.self, B.self]
let decoded: [P] = possibleTypes.compactMap { try? container.decode($0, forKey: .instanceOfProtocol) }
guard let instance = decoded.first else { throw NoConformingTypeError() }
instanceOfProtocol = instance
```

This feels like the best option so far, but doesn't compile due to `Ambiguous reference to member 'decode(_:forKey:)'`.

Edit:

## Option 4: Using a Generic Type:

```swift
struct S<T: P>: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let instanceOfProtocol: T
}
```

This is really nice, because synthesis of `Decodable` works again!

However, now we have to know what type `T` will be, because the decoding site now requires a type:

```swift
try JSONDecoder().decode(S<A>.self, from: data)
try JSONDecoder().decode(S<B>.self, from: data)
```

In our use case, we can't know what the type will be before, so we'd have to check here again...

Comment: If you can't know what the type will be before, you can't decode it to well known type.

Comment: Because you simply can not check all decodable types of the world. There should be something to tell you what type is that like an enum or something.

Comment: What you're noticing here is the difference between nominal ("(of a role or status) existing in name only.") and structural typing. JSON is structurally typed. Each of the object's types is really just a reflection of its fields. If two objects have the same fields, they could be thought to have the same type. This is not the case in Swift, where the names of types is their sole source of identity. For Swift to know how to decode `P`, its not sufficient to know what the fields of `P` are. It needs to know precisely which type to decode as.

Answer (score 2):

Use generic type:

```
struct S<T: P>: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let instanceOfProtocol: T
}
```

Remember `Protocol` is not a `Type`! And Swift is strongly typed language. So it MUST know the type of all objects at first place even though the actual type is not exposable to the caller of the object.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I tried that before. While this is very nice (because `Decodable` can be synthesized), it just moves the type disambiguation to the call site: `try? JSONDecoder().decode(S<A>.self, from: json1)`